# Jmeter random requests

Tags: csv, jmeter

I want to test a web application. Lets say that i have a php script that i want to test

```
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=??
```

The jmeter.php with method GET reads an id that refers to each test!
I have all my ids to a csv file and i read them with the CSV data set config.

```
CSV file
8
9
10
```

If i set the number of threads (users) to 3 i get 3 requests BUT is the same request!

```
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=8
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=8
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=8
```

**What i want? The following**:

```
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=8
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=9
www.example.com/jmeter.php?runtest=10
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
set sharing mode : All Threads
```

in csv config component.

Comment: currently no provision for randomness in csv file in jmeter

Comment: for now you can put numbers in random order in csv file that way same purpose will be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Though this was not available at the time this question was originally asked, there is now the [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) plugin which is available for JMeter.  It accomplishes exactly what the original question asks, which is to select values from rows at random from a CSV source file.

You can set your CSV data source file using the "*Filename*" parameter, and when the "*Random order*" box is checked, rows will be read in random order instead of sequentially:

[image: Configuration page for the Random CSV Data Set Config plugin element]

This can be added to your JMeter test plan though the Plugins Manager from the *Options* menu:

[image: Accessing the Plugins Manager from the JMeter Options Menu]

The Random CSV Data Set Config element is one of the [most popular plugins](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2023/08/overlooked-jmeter-plugins/) in use today that is often overlooked by new test designers, as it must be first enabled though the Plugins Manager as described above.